# Linq query need correct sum

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am using .NET 4 Data Visualization Charts and am using a Linq query to get the data for the chart. I am new to Linq so not sure on how to word this query. Here is what it does, I have the follwoing tables its pulling data from

1. Orders
2. ShipmentSchedule

The orders table has the Product that was ordered, the OrderId, the amount that was shipped and the remaining quantity for that order. One order can only have a single product in it. I am trying to get all the Ordershipments in the class OrderShipment, make a List<> for it and group it by each product and show the total quantity for each product that was ordered and what has been shipped. The query below sums up the quantity shipped for all orders which is correct but because it is making a list of OrderShipments, I want the remaining quantity for each order across all shipments and sum that up by the product. Right now its adding up the remaining quantity for all the shipments which is wrong since an Order has the same Remaining Quantity across all shipments.  how can I get the remaining quantity for each product so thw query adds up the Remaining quantity by each order correctly?? Please provide an example with code how to accomplish this if you have a suggestion, your helps really appreciated, thanks

```
 private class ChartDataPoint
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double QtyRemaining { get; set; }
        public double QtyShipped { get; set; }
    }

    private class OrderShipment
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double QuantityRemaining { get; set; }
        public double QuantityShipped { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
    }


      List<OrderShipment> productsOrdered =
          (from os in Statistics.OptimalShipments
           from o in Statistics.OrdersPlaced
           where ((os.Date >= Statistics.ShippingWindowStartDate) &&
                   (os.Date <= Statistics.ShippingWindowEndDate) &&
                   (os.OrderId == o.OrderId) &&
                  ((o.ClientLocationId == ClientLocation.ClientLocationId)))
           select new OrderShipment()
           {
               ProductName = o.Product.Name,
               QuantityRemaining = o.RemainingQuantity,
               QuantityShipped = os.QuantityShipped,

           }).ToList();

        var query = productsOrdered.GroupBy(p => p.ProductName);
        List<ChartDataPoint> chartDataPoints = new List<ChartDataPoint>();
        foreach (var productGroup in query)
        {
            chartDataPoints.Add(new ChartDataPoint()
            {
               ProductName = productGroup.Key,

               // This is obv wrong this sums up the Remaining quantity across   
               // all shipments for a order when we should be only taking the 
               //Remaining quantity once for each order across all shipments.
               QtyRemaining = productGroup.Sum(po => po.QuantityRemaining),
               QtyShipped = productGroup.Sum(po => po.QuantityShipped)
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it your productGroup should have a lot of `OrderShipment` objects grouped by their product name. You then want to sum the QuantityShipped and the QuantityRemaining should all be the same and you want to just take this value?

If so then this should do you:

```
QtyRemaining = productGroup.First();
```

If I have misunderstood you may want to simplify the explanation, perhaps with an example...